# Symfony 4.4 : could not find driver when make:entity relation field but php -m show active driver pdo_pgsql

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I need to add to my entity `Agency`, a relation to the `Country` entity. When I run `php bin/console make:entity Agency` I can add string fields, int fields, etc... But when I wan to add my `country` field with type `relation`, Doctrine shows up an error :

> In PDOConnection.php line 31:
>
> could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 27:
>
> could not find driver

I looked in my `php.ini` to see which driver what active by running `php -m` and my driver `pdo_pgsql` is active.

In my `doctrine.yaml` file :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
                server_version: '15.1'
```

I really don't see what am I doing wrong... Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the environment is the same? Perhaps you are not loading the same .env file, so your database_url is different and has the initial value which is pdo_mysql.

Comment: Yes, when I run `php bin/console debug:config doctrine --env=dev` it shows the `pdo_pgsql` driver. The strangest things is that `make:migration`, `doctrine:migrations:migrate` works well. It's just the `make:entity` that bug. I can add relation by hand but I would have preferred to access the maker tool :D

Comment: Oh yes, I'd rather to use maker tool too ! ;D Clear your cache and retry. If it's still bugging, you should create an issue on symfony, beacause it seems to be a bug more than a config problem. Do not forget to mention that doctrine:migrations:migrate works fine. Maker bundle has been updated recently, but I do not see updates on this part of codes. There is "only" new makers in the last update.

Comment: Okay Alexandre I'll try that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The debug:config won't tell you if the configuration is OK. Does it work when running sql with: `php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "select a from ( values ('foo'), ('bar'), ('fooBar') ) s(a);"`?

Comment: Hey, yes it works fine :)